# Slicing for Substrings

Tags: python, python-3.x, substring, slice

I am asked to have a string loop and print in reverse. I can get it to  do this but why praytell is the last letter starting it off...

```
data = "Why am I doing this is reverse order."

for index in range(len(data)):
    print(index, data[-index])

0 W
1 .
2 r
3 e
4 d
5 r
6 o
7  
...
```

Ah this is the closest I have come....not adding data[:-index], [-index:]...they are all wrong...

```
data = "Why am I doing this is reverse order."

for index in range(len(data)):
    print(index, data[-index])


0 W
1 .
2 r
3 e
4 d
5 r
6 o
7  
...
```

Comment: `print(index, data[-index-1])`

Comment: Because lists have 0-based indexing forwards but you're out-by-one doing it in reverse (-1, not -0 is the last index). Consequently you end up looping around to the start of the list

Comment: There is a nice table in the [Strings](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#strings) section of the Tutorial that shows how positive and negative indexing work. It is the sixteenth example - or search the page for `One way to remember how slices work`

Comment: I see. Thanks very much. I totally get it now. =D

Comment: My book is ok in explaining it, so thanks for the additional nfo/link. Everyone is so helpful here.

Answer (score 2):

Dont use only `-` but substrac the index to the string len:

```
data = "Why am I doing this is reverse order."

l = len(data) - 1
for index in range(l+1):
    print(index, data[l-index])
```

Output:

```
0 .
1 r
2 e
...
34 y
35 h
36 W
```

Alternatively the **pythonic** way of doing this would be using `reversed`:

```
for l in reversed(data):
    print(l)
```

Also you can use slicing, `data[::-1]` but I would avoid this unless you want a **reversed copy** of the string.

Comment: I greatly appreciate your assistance and prompt response. Very good. I see my error. Thanks. =D

Comment: You are welcome @ManWithDirtyGlasses, consider reading this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

If you want it printed as a sentence, you can also:

```py
reversed_data = data[::-1]
print(reversed_data)
```

OR

```py
reversed_data = reversed(data)
print("".join(list(reversed_data)))
```

Or, if you want it character by character:

```py
reversed_data = data[::-1]
for char in reversed_data:
    print(char)
```

```py
reversed_data = reversed(data)
for char in reversed_data:
    print(char)
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your implementation doesn't work is because `range(len(data))` starts at 0 up to n-1. However when your get `data[-index]` where index is 0 it return the 0 element of the string; the first letter.

An easy implementation is:

```
data = 'Hello world!'

# Print every letter on different line
for x in data[::-1]:
    print(x)

# Print the reverse string on one line
print(data[::-1])
```

refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation) for how slicing works in python.

Comment: Cool. Thanks for the link also. =)